# How to determine top 3 column values for each row

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe in the format

```
| ID | Payer | Payee | Mode1 | Probability1 | Mode2 | Probability2 | Mode3  | Probability3 | Mode4  | Probability4 | Month  |
|----|-------|-------|-------|--------------|-------|--------------|--------|--------------|--------|--------------|--------|
| 1  | xyz   | wqu   | cash  | 0.16         | wire  | 0.89         | upi    | 0.81         | cheque | 0.69         | 201801 |
| 2  | wqu   | xyz   | wire  | 0.28         | cash  | 0.19         | upi    | 0.77         | cheque | 0.58         | 201801 |
| 3  | pqr   | xyz   | upi   | 0.35         | cash  | 0.11         | cheque | 0.48         | wire   | 0.66         | 201803 |
```

The probability column has corresponding values for Mode column

Now I want to get top 3 probability values by columns for each row

Something like this,

```
| ID | Payer | Payee | Mode1 | Probability1 | Mode2 | Probability2 | Mode3  | Probability3 | Mode4  | Probability4 | Month  | Top1Mode | Top1Value | Top2Mode | Top2Value | Top3Mode | Top3Value |
|----|-------|-------|-------|--------------|-------|--------------|--------|--------------|--------|--------------|--------|----------|-----------|----------|-----------|----------|-----------|
| 1  | xyz   | wqu   | cash  | 0.16         | wire  | 0.89         | upi    | 0.81         | cheque | 0.69         | 201801 | wire     | 0.89      | upi      | 0.81      | cheque   | 0.69      |
| 2  | wqu   | xyz   | wire  | 0.28         | cash  | 0.19         | upi    | 0.77         | cheque | 0.58         | 201801 | upi      | 0.77      | cheque   | 0.58      | wire     | 0.28      |
| 3  | pqr   | xyz   | upi   | 0.35         | cash  | 0.11         | cheque | 0.48         | wire   | 0.66         | 201803 | wire     | 0.66      | cheque   | 0.48      | upi      | 0.35      |
```

In case the table is not visible
[image]

To explain it further, For row 1 or ID 1. Wire has the highest probability (i.e. 0.89) so it's in Top1Mode Column along with its value in next column. Similarly, UPI has the 2nd highest probability so it's in Top2Mode Column along with it's value in next column (i.e. Top2Value)

Doing it using Pandas or PySpark, any of them works for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing I can think of is using UDF (but I would like to see if anyone has a better solution):

```py
@UDF
def getProbability(Mode1, Probability1, Mode2, Probability2, Mode3, Probability3, Mode4, Probability4, num, mode):
    prob_list = []
    prob_list.append((Mode1, Probability1))
    prob_list.append((Mode2, Probability2))
    prob_list.append((Mode3, Probability3))
    prob_list.append((Mode4, Probability4))
    prob_list = sorted(prob_list, key = lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
        
    if mode == "Mode":
        return prob_list[num][0]
    else:
        return prob_list[num][1]

df = df.withColumn("Top1Mode", getProbability("Mode1", "Probability1", "Mode2", "Probability2", "Mode3", "Probability3", "Mode4", "Probability4", lit(0), lit("Mode"))) \
       .withColumn("Top1Value", getProbability("Mode1", "Probability1", "Mode2", "Probability2", "Mode3", "Probability3", "Mode4", "Probability4", lit(0), lit("Prob"))) \
       .withColumn("Top2Mode", getProbability("Mode1", "Probability1", "Mode2", "Probability2", "Mode3", "Probability3", "Mode4", "Probability4", lit(1), lit("Mode"))) \
       .withColumn("Top2Value", getProbability("Mode1", "Probability1", "Mode2", "Probability2", "Mode3", "Probability3", "Mode4", "Probability4", lit(1), lit("Prob"))) \
       .withColumn("Top3Mode", getProbability("Mode1", "Probability1", "Mode2", "Probability2", "Mode3", "Probability3", "Mode4", "Probability4", lit(2), lit("Mode"))) \
       .withColumn("Top3Value", getProbability("Mode1", "Probability1", "Mode2", "Probability2", "Mode3", "Probability3", "Mode4", "Probability4", lit(2), lit("Prob")))
```

Comment: When trying to run this without @udf decorator, I'm getting `ValueError: Cannot convert column into bool: please use '&' for 'and', '|' for 'or', '~' for 'not' when building DataFrame boolean expressions` on line `if mode == "Mode"`

With decorator, there's another error

Comment: Turns out there's some issue while using this function within a class, putting it outside of the class scope solves the issue for now